# ElasticSearch Templates for filters

Tags: templates, elasticsearch, filter

I'm new to elastic search. From what I understand there are two types of templates: Template Query & Search Template.
Based on [this](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/template-query-vs-search-template/20517) post and their descriptions on the elastic reference doc. it looks like both are templates for queries.

Because filters have better performance than queries I want to create filter templates.

Is there some way to do this, I feel like there must be.

Thanks!

FYI, if it's important I'm using the JAVA API to interact with Elasticsearch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create filter templates. There is nothing special about a search template that excludes filters. In fact they have some pretty good examples in the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-template.html).

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "line": "{{text}}" 
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        {{#line_no}} 
          "range": {
            "line_no": {
              {{#start}} 
                "gte": "{{start}}" 
                {{#end}},{{/end}} 
              {{/start}} 
              {{#end}} 
                "lte": "{{end}}" 
              {{/end}} 
            }
          }
        {{/line_no}} 
      }
    }
  }
}
```